# How different when using, is or was?

Tags: tense

She donated all her money to others. I think she **was** a true example of noblesse oblige

I think i can use **is** instead of **was..**
There is any meaning difference between two?

Answer (score 1):

- **I think she was a true example of noblesse oblige**

This sentence denotes *past* tense. This indicates that you are describing something about her that was in the past. Probably she is not alive anymore.

- **I think she is a true example of noblesse oblige**

This sentence denotes *present* tense. This indicates that you are describing something is still here. Like she is alive and such.

Answer (score 1):

> She donated all her money to others. I think she was a true example of
>   noblesse oblige.

I'm not sure that this is a correct usage of *noblesse oblige* but ignoring that, I would expect:

> Present: She **donates** all her money to others. I think she **is** a
>   true example ...
>
> Past: She **donated** all her money to others. I think she **was** a
>   true example ...

Answer (score 0):

The tense are just different:

- She was in the past (for example last year), but no longer today:

> **Past:** I think she **was** a true example of noblesse.

- She is still today:

> **Present:** I think she **is** a true example of noblesse.

Comment: Can you tell me how different meaning two of them have subtly?

Comment: Of course, I updated my reply, feel free to ask me if it is still unclear.